# Where to keep Subscriptions in SAAS application built on Pimcore (PHP, Symfony)

Tags: pimcore

Stack used:

- Pimcore 11 on Symfony
- https://github.com/pimcore/customer-data-framework for Customers
- League/oauth2-client for Social Login

Tariffs for SAAS Application:

- free
- small
- mid
- big

**Question:
How to decide where to keep those tariffs and their recurring payments?**

My suggestions:

- external API like [www.salable.app](http://www.salable.app) and just update one boolean attribute in Customer dataObject
- as Products in pimcore/ecommerce-framework-bundle (e.g. like it is done in official Demo application)
- as Products in https://github.com/coreshop/CoreShop